# delegatecall in Brownie

Tags: solidity, python, brownie, delegatecall

I am trying to perform **delegatecall** in Brownie solving the Delegation task in the Ethernaut app in order to claim ownership of the Delegate contract (see below).
What is the equivalent of the following solution (which worked in Ethernaut App) `sendTransaction({from: player, to: contract.address, data: web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature("pwn()")})` in **Brownie**?

My solution keeps failing due to: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'`

My solution is:

```py
data_to_send = keccak(text="pwn()")[0:4].hex()
my_account.transfer(delegate_contract_address, data_to_send, {"from": my_account})
```

Is there anyone who could help me with that, please?
Thank you in advance.

Contract: (also can be seen here [Ethernaut 6. Delegation](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493))

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Delegate {

  address public owner;

  constructor(address _owner) public {
    owner = _owner;
  }

  function pwn() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}

contract Delegation {

  address public owner;
  Delegate delegate;

  constructor(address _delegateAddress) public {
    delegate = Delegate(_delegateAddress);
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  fallback() external {
    (bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
    if (result) {
      this;
    }
  }
}
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\pracovni\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\pracovni\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\delegation.py", line 30, in main
    claim_ownership_of_delegate_contract()
  File ".\scripts\delegation.py", line 23, in claim_ownership_of_delegate_contract
    my_account.transfer(delegate_contract_address, data_to_send, {"from": my_account})
  File "C:\Users\pracovni\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 644, in transfer
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\pracovni\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 723, in _make_transaction     
    gas_limit = Wei(gas_limit) or self._gas_limit(
  File "C:\Users\pracovni\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\convert\datatypes.py", line 47, in __new__
    return super().__new__(cls, _to_wei(value))  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\pracovni\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\convert\datatypes.py", line 108, in _to_wei
    return _return_int(original, value)
  File "C:\Users\pracovni\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\convert\datatypes.py", line 122, in _return_int
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'
```

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question, because it does not have the source code or ABI of the relevant smart contract. Please edit the question and add the details.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa edited and details added. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Do you also have a full trackeback for the error?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa yes, I have. Added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [Brownie's Account class documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=account#account) you will find out that the parameters for `transfer()` are:

```
Account.transfer(self, to=None, amount=0, gas_limit=None, gas_price=None, max_fee=None, priority_fee=None, data=None, nonce=None, required_confs=1, allow_revert=None, silent=False)
```

You are passing `data_to_send` to `amount`. Amount is the ETH amount attached to the transaction, not a data field.

Comment: Oh, I see. Silly me. Thank you very much!